# Reactjs Invariant Violation with npm module (react-loader)

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs

I am trying to get [react-loader](https://github.com/quickleft/react-loader) to work with my react component.

Currently I I have this following snippet:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Loader = require('react-loader');


var DisplayController = React.createClass({      

    // etc ..

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            active_tab: 0,
            tabs: [],
            groupsData: {
                objects: [{sub_groups:[]}]
            }, 
            itemsData: {objects: []},
            active_sub_tab: "Most Recent",
            loaded :false
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.getGroupsApi();
        this.getItemsApi();
    },
    render: function() {

        return (<Loader loaded={this.state.loaded}> <MainMenu/>  </Loader>);
    }
});
```

When I added this  code, it started giving me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a
>   ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add
>   a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not
>   created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering
>   this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the
>   ref.

I am following the directions provided by the module, why would I be receiving this error?

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem.  Have raised as an issue https://github.com/quickleft/react-loader/issues/22

Comment: Double check through your scripts that you're not loading multiple copies of React

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue too, and my reason for this is "multiple React".
I use React with Bower, and I use this react-loader with npm(browserify).
So I change React with npm, this problem was solved.